# Getting html file's content which is in a package

Tags: java, html, string, class, javafx

I have added an html file into my JavaFX Project structure. This file and `Controller` class are in the same folder of the project. How can I use that file's content as a string in `Controller` class?

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
String line;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/Untitled.html"));
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();
```

**Project structure**

[image: screenshot of project structure]

Comment: Please post the code. Not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `Class.getResourceAsStream` or `ClassLoader`'s equivalent to access a `InputStream` for a resource:

```
try (InputStream is = Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample/Untitled.html");
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

In the code above I assume resource is available in the subdirectory `sample` in the classpath at runtime. Depending on the way the resource is stored at runtime, it may not be accessible as file; e.g. you cannot access resources stored as entries in a `.jar` file as files.